# Scala getLines() with yield not as I expect

Tags: scala

My understanding of the "Programming in Scala" book is that the following should return an `Array[String]` when instead it returns an `Iterator[String]`. What am I missing?

```
val data = for (line <- Source.fromFile("data.csv").getLines()) yield line
```

I'm using Scala 2.9.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The chapter you want to read to understand what's happening is http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html

```
for (x <- expr_1) yield expr_2
```

is translated to

```
expr_1.map(x => expr_2)
```

So if `expr_1` is an `Iterator[String]` as it is in your case, then `expr_1.map(line => line)` is also an `Iterator[String]`.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it returns an `Iterator`. See: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.BufferedSource

But the following should work if an `Array` is your goal:

```
Source.fromFile("data.csv").getLines().toArray
```

If you want to convert an `Iterator` to an `Array` (as mentioned in your comment), then try the following after you've yielded your `Iterator`:

```
data.toArray
```

Comment: Thanks.  The code I omitted extracts bits from each line so that the final `Array` is only made up of those bits.  In the solution you provide, the entire file is made into an `Array`, which I would then need to cut down, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Yes it does.  Thanks.  I still don't get why `getLines()`returns an `Iterator`and whether things have changed since the book was written or whether I am misunderstanding it, but you've certainly solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@dhg is correct and here is a bit more detail on why.

The code in your example calls calls Source.fromFile which returns a BufferedSource. Then you call getLines which returns an iterator. That iterator is then yielded and stored as data.

Calling toArray on the Iterator will get you an array of Strings like you want.

Comment: Thanks too.  I thought that `line <-` would call the `Iterator[String]` that getLines() returns so that it returned a String each time, and that String was what was yielded.